# Send keys Java code is not working on Mac

Tags: java, macos, automation, robotframework

This code is used for automation purposes in robotframework. After a right mouse click on the finder window, I want to send keys like "e", "d" etc. and select an item from the context menu. This is the Java code:

```
    public void sendKeys(String text) throws Exception {
    int len = text.length();
    char curr;
    for (int index=0; index<len; index++) {
      curr = text.toUpperCase().charAt(index);
      assertTrue(
        String.format("'%c' is not an alphanumeric character", curr),
        (curr>=KeyEvent.VK_A && curr<=KeyEvent.VK_Z) || (curr>=KeyEvent.VK_0 && curr<=KeyEvent.VK_9)
      );
      robot.keyPress(curr);
      robot.keyRelease(curr);
    }
    System.out.println("Send Keys "+text);
  }
```

On windows (almost all versions), I am perfectly able to send keys, but on Mac Sierra/El Capitan it doesn't throw an error but it actually selects the file instead. I've tried different combinations of send keys input like "e", "d", "o" etc , using all these inputs the file is getting selected instead of actually selecting the items on the context menu.

PS: The context menu has the items which I'm using in my input for send keys.

Comment: Are you sure that isn't the expected behavior on a Mac?

Comment: Ya, I'm sure. I tried manually and I'm able to select the item from the context menu

Comment: Not sure about MAC problem, but do you use keypress and release all the time? I normally use keyPress and release only when I am using a SHIFT or CTRL. Try without the keyRelease!

Comment: I have my version of enterString too, which you can try out, if you want. but I never tested it on MAC

Comment: @Waman - I tried the code without keyRelease and it didn't work. Can you share the enterString code and I will try on Mac?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I use:

```
public static void enterString(String value)
    {   
        String Keyvalue=value.toUpperCase();
        //System.out.println(Keyvalue);
        for (int i=0;i<Keyvalue.length();i++)
        {
            //System.out.println(Keyvalue.charAt(i));
            if(Keyvalue.charAt(i) == ':')
            {
                System.out.println("its a colon");
                RoboKey.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT);
                RoboKey.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_SEMICOLON);
                RoboKey.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_SEMICOLON);
                RoboKey.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT);

            }
            else if (Keyvalue.charAt(i) == '.')
            {
                RoboKey.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_PERIOD);
            }
            else if (Keyvalue.charAt(i) == '_')
            {
               RoboKey.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT);
               RoboKey.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_MINUS);
               RoboKey.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_MINUS);
               RoboKey.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT);
            }
            else
            {
               RoboKey.keyPress((int)Keyvalue.charAt(i));
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: [link] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40812032/numpad-5-for-right-click-on-mac-is-not-working-using-robotframework) Can you please check this one as well if you have some input then let me know.