# NUMPAD 5 for right click on mac is not working using robotframework

Tags: macos, javafx, robotframework

I am using robotframework for automation of desktop application. I'm trying to do a right click on Mac Sierra and then use send keys to select the items generated on the context menu. I have activated mouse keys settings from the accessibility setting so that NUMPAD 5 will behave as a right click on mouse pointer. The problem is when I use this command it actually does a right click but when I try to use the send keys command the context menu disappears. So, I'm not able to select items from the context menu. Here is the code for right click:

```
public void pressCtrl(String key) throws Exception {
if(key.contains("NUMPAD")){
                             int keyvalue = key.charAt(6);
                             int keycode = keyvalue + 48;       
                              assertTrue(
                 String.format("'%c' is not an alphanumeric character", keycode),
                 (keycode >=KeyEvent.VK_A && keycode <=KeyEvent.VK_Z) || (keycode >=KeyEvent.VK_0 && keycode <=KeyEvent.VK_9)  || (keycode >=KeyEvent.VK_NUMPAD0 && keycode <=KeyEvent.VK_NUMPAD9)
                );               
             System.out.println("Press CTRL+"+key);
             robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
             robot.keyPress(keycode);
             robot.delay(50);
             robot.keyRelease(keycode);
             robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
```

So the sequence of command on robotframework is :

```
Press Ctrl    NUMPAD5
Send Keys    E
Press    Enter
```

**What I think and have tried:**
I'm not able to identify why the context menu generated from the right click disappears while trying to use the send keys. I have tried this combination manually, it seems there is certain timing when right click disappears when key is released. I tried difference combinations of timings with my automation script but all the time I find same behavior. The same script and java code works fine on Windows.

Comment: I guess SendKeys works well only on windows. Can u give a screenshot of the right click menu? I feel when you do a right click, the control might not be by default shifted to right click menu! and when you press keys with focus on some other element it would disappear for sure! check if you need to use "tab" or "tabs" to get focus on the menu.